# How to open "file://D:/help.html#selclass" with default browser in C#

Tags: c#, url, browser, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open in default browser in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c)

How to open "file://D:/help.html#selclass" with default browser in C#, is there any example?

Thanks
Dma

Comment: i don't think so. my main target is "#selclass"; and it's true that "Process.Start("file://D:/help.html#selclass"); " can open "help.html", but "#selclass" doesn't work. "#selclass" is removed by IE (test in ie7).

Comment: More detail: process.start("iexplore", "D:/help.html#selclass"); but IE may not the default browser. and when I get default browser from register. firefox doesn't work with #selclass, firefox replace # by %23. can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got default browser firstly through register table; and then call

```
Process.Start(browser, url);
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("file://D:/help.html#selclass");
```

Comment: i don't think so. my main target is "#selclass"; and it's true that "Process.Start("file://D:/help.html#selclass"); " can open "help.html", but "#selclass" doesn't work. "#selclass" is removed by IE (test in ie7).

Comment: Could you pass it as a parameter? for example file://D:/help.html?cl=selclass

Comment: The IE only open "help.html" and remove "?cl=selclass"; you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = Process.Start(@"D:\help.html");
while (!p.HasExited) Thread.Sleep(10);

// carry on
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Create a temporary `.URL` file (see [here](http://www.cyanwerks.com/file-format-url.html) for instance) that features `#selclass` in the URL.
2. Open the `.URL` using `Process.Start(...)`.
3. Delete the temporary `.URL` file.

Comment: Thanks so much! does it work in firefox? it's an unoffice solution, how about win7/winxp or IE7/IE8?

Comment: .URLs work with whatever the default browser is. And the file format spans Windows 7 back to Windows 9x I believe.