# How do I open default browser in fullscreen mode from a C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sendkeys

Hi & thanks for looking!

How do I open default browser in fullscreen mode from a C# desktop application?  I have seen similar questions on SO:

[How to open in default browser in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp)

. . .BUT nothing addresses opening a local HTML file (C: drive) in a FULLSCREEN browser window from C#.

I can open the window using this:

```
Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

But how do I make it default to fullscreen?  Is there a way to simulate the F11 key press, or even something more direct?

EDIT: Ideally, I will not need to have a form open.  I don't want to confuse the issue, but I am experimenting with the Kinect Speech Recognition engine and will have a program running in the system tray, always listening.  I already have it to a point that I can say a command and it will. . .

```
//do stuff
```

. . .and in this case, I just want it to open the default browser in fullscreen mode.

So, I don't have to be able to toggle back and forth between fullscreen and regular screen, just launch in fullscreen.  I was thinking that a simulation of the F11 press would be the answer, but it sounds like I need a form open for this??

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: There is no standard mechanism for this, every browser implement their "maximized with no frame" mode differently.  ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle is all you got.

Comment: F11 appears to work for Chrome, Firefox and IE; while there's no clear standard this seems to get ~90% of popular browsers out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you would need to use [sendkeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Looking at the list you need something like:

`ActiveForm.SendKeys("{F11}");`

Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: SendKeys requires a form handle and I'm guessing the default browser won't necessarily be a subform of his application.

Comment: @M.Babcock for me, I find sendkeys does it for any activeform, for instance, you can use send keys to spam notepad after creating that process

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't the SendKeys need to be

```
ActiveForm.SendKeys.Send("{F11}");
```

instead of

```
ActiveForm.SendKeys("{F11}");
```