# C# Webbrowser open with Default browser

Tags: browser

always open with IE, how to open with Defalut browser,like firefox or chrome

Comment: How are you opening the links?  Please provide a code sample.

Comment: There are a few threads on it already

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp

Comment: The WebBrowser control or "a link"?

Answer (score 2):

Go to solution explorer -> right click on project -> select Browse with 
it will open a **Browse with** window, having a list of available browser in your pc 
select it to browse or make selected browser as default browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
   public MyWebBrowser() : base(){ }

   protected override void OnNewWindow(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
   {
      try
      {
         Process.Start(StatusText);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         //Display error message
      }
      e.Cancel = true;
      base.OnNewWindow(e);
   }
}
```

EDIT: Never mind, this won't work well. It will open the link the mouse is over instead on the one the user actually clicks (if they use the keyboard to click) and it is a huge security risk.

Comment: I think this answer might fit better anyways: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4580263/938695