# C# Hyperlink in TextBlock: nothing happens when I click on it

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, textblock, navigateuri

In my C# standalone application, I want to let users click on a link that would launch their favorite browser.

```
System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
Run run = new Run("Link Text");

Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(run);
link.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://w3.org");
text.Inlines.Add(link);
```

The link is displayed correctly.

When I move the mouse over it, the link becomes red.

PROBLEM: When I click it, nothing happens.

Did I forget something? Do I need to implement some kind of method to really let the link be opened?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to handle the hyperlink's `RequestNavigate` event. Here's a quick way of doing it:

```
link.RequestNavigate += (sender, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Are you handling the 'Hyperlink.RequestNavigate' event? When a user clicks a Hyperlink in a WPF window it doesn't automatically open a browser with the URI specified in its NavigateUri property.

In your code-behind you can do something like:

```
link.RequestNavigate += LinkOnRequestNavigate;

private void LinkOnRequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
}
```

Comment: WPF Hyperlink is nearly useless.  I want it to launch the URL using url set in xaml, otherwise why don't I just use a label and button with my view viewmodel.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a global hyperlink handler in your App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
        typeof(System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink),
        System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink.RequestNavigateEvent,
        new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(
            (sender, en) => Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(
                en.Uri.ToString()
            ) { UseShellExecute = true })
        )
    );
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

This assumes all the NavigateUri properties refer to something you want to launch, but you can always make the handler take care of edge cases.

Comment: This doesn't work in .NET 6.0

Comment: Actually it was 5 that broke it, it needs UseShellExecute = true

Comment: Actually it should be `en.Uri.ToString()` instead of `e.Uri.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

For those in .Net Core, the way you do this has changed. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232486/10227808) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066710/10227808).

```cs
link.RequestNavigate += (sender, e) =>
{
    var url = e.Uri.ToString();
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(url)
    { 
        UseShellExecute = true 
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with a command is also possible:

```
<TextBlock>
    See our <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://www.example.com" Command="{Binding OpenPrivacyPolicyCommand}">Privacy Policy</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

The command needs to call open the URL then:

```
Process.Start(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using MVVM

*In your .xaml*

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="Gold buyers " /><Hyperlink Command="{Binding ViewGoldBuyersGuideCommand}" ><Run Text="guide" /></Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

*And in your vm.cs file*

```
public ICommand ViewGoldBuyersGuideCommand { get; private set; }

ViewGoldBuyersGuideCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnViewGoldBuyersGuide); // inside your constructor

private void OnViewGoldBuyersGuide(object obj)
{
    Process.Start("https://example.com/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On MVVM:

```xml
<TextBlock>         
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding OpenHyperlinkCommand}" CommandParameter="https://www.google.com/">Google</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

```cs
ICommand OpenHyperlinkCommand {get;}

OpenHyperlinkCommand = new RelayCommand(url => Process.Start(url as string));
```