# Process.Start with .NET Core 2.0 on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I am trying to start the default web browser open to a link with `Process.Start()`. I use `Process.Start("https://www.google.com")`, but my .NET Core App crashes with the following:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception An
> unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
> occurred in System.Diagnostics.Process.dll: 'No such file or
> directory'    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ResolvePath(String
> filename)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo
> startInfo)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    at
> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)    at
> VPGameHelper.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> /home/jj/VPGameHelper/Program.cs:line 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

[Process.Start for URLs on .NET Core](https://brockallen.com/2016/09/24/process-start-for-urls-on-net-core/)

The original question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp) where.

```
public static void OpenBrowser(string url)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(url);
    }
    catch
    {
        // hack because of this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10361
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            url = url.Replace("&", "^&");
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") { CreateNoWindow = true });
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            Process.Start("xdg-open", url);
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
        {
            Process.Start("open", url);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. I need to make sure and surround my url in quotes for xdg-open.