# Having c# windows application and web application together

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, hybrid

I have one windows application developed in c# and one web application developed in asp.net and MVC. Now i want a mechanism like when i press button in windows application it should open this web application preferably in IIS it self so that my web application is viewed in browser. kindly help with this as my final year project is pending due to this

Answer (score 0):

You just have to open the URL of the Web server.
See: [How to open in default browser in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp)

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "http://google.com" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to first host your web app and provide it URL to the button click like
    Response.Redirect("Your URL");

If use want to test this before having your web app hosted , You have to put both the project in one Solution and in Properties of it  you need to set both the projects as startup project. No doubt your web app will also open but for time being you can ignore that window and can check whether the redirecting of URL is working.