# How generate Oauth2 OIDC Authorization code in .net c#

Tags: server, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identity, wso2-identity-server

when the below request comes to my provider, the provider should generate the code and send it back how can I generate this code in asp.net c# .

```
client_id=11111
response_type=code
scope= 
redirect 
state=state-22222
```

response :
Code:?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to initialize the authorise request with these parameters in the browser.

Here is the sample request

```
https://<is-domain>:<id-host>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client-id>&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri>&scope=<scope>&state=<state>
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp) to open a browser from your C# application.

2. Then the user has to complete the authentication flow and approve the consent.
3. Then code will be sent back as a query parameter to the call back URL you have defined. From that, you can get the code