# How to open new browser window in C#, WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, browser, winui-3

I am trying to open a URL in a new browser window. Specifically, **a new browser window**. The following code launches the URL in the default browser, but always opens the URL as a new tab *in an existing browser window* (if one exists). I want to launch the new tab in a new browser window, regardless of if one (or more) browser windows are already open.

This code launches the URL in WinUI 3 (in a new tab in an existing browser window), and appears to be the simplest:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"));
```

This code does the same thing, and also works in WinUI 3 ([credit to this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp)):

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; 
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "http://google.com";
myProcess.Start();
```

Please note that the following code **does NOT** work at all in WinUI 3:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

**EDIT: Additional Ruled-out Method**

The following modification of `Process.Start()` works in WinUI 3, but like the above methods only opens new tabs in existing browser windows, and thus is not a solution to the question above (also note that it forces using a specific browser, rather than the default browser):

```
Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe", "http://google.com");
```

Comment: Whether a new tab or window is opened depends on how the default browser is implemented or configured...which browser are you using? The solution is not necessary the same for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
_ = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://fakeurl.tld"));
```

Should be handled by whichever program is supposed to handle HTTP URIs

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling a JavaScript command into webview2:

`await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.open('http://www.bing.com');");`

Make sure you have either set the source of `webView`, or that you have already called `EnsureCoreWebView2Async()`.