# c# WebBrowser control opens link in IE rather than the WebBrowser itself

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control on my c# form. When I click on a link in the html on the WebBrowser, the link html is displayed in a new IE rather than on the WebBrowser itself. How can I open the link on the WebBrowser itself only?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580324/8469314) what is the default for `WebBrowser` and the recommendation is to make a change in the `Navigating event`. You can check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use the all the default settings for the WebBrowser. In the navigating event, if I set the cancel = true, then the link won't be opened at ll.

Comment: I found the issue is related to the web sites. If I browse bbc.com, the link opens in the WebBrowser itself, but the link in https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=en-AU&gl=AU&ceid=AU:en will open in IE.