# C#: how to open URL in a default browser that contains equals sign

Tags: c#

Usually, I use `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://google.com")` and it works fine, but if URL contains `=`, it just opens `explorer.exe`

How can I make URLs with equals sign open in a browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open in default browser in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm voting to [leave this question open](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/35038709) because none of the linked answers mention issues with certain characters like equal signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```cs
string url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=openai";

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = url,
    UseShellExecute = true
};

Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found this solution:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("https://127.0.0.1?param=value"){
                UseShellExecute = true
            });
```

It's opening default browser in my case. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you specify explorer.exe for a URL? Let the default browser open your URL like:

```
Process.Start("https://www.google.com/?q=software");
```

**Edit:** The default value of the `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` property is `true` on .NET Framework apps and `false` on .NET Core apps. So if you are using .NET Core or later, you need to set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` to successfully open the browser.