# Download file in browser client in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have URL and it is displaying file OR image.

Now When any user click on Download link then that URL file should download in browser.

I am using C#.. I have tried following code but it is downloading file in Project folder.

But I want to download that file in browser itself.. Any idea how to do that ?

```
string path = "some url";
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(path,"image.png");
}
```

Comment: How does this code know there even is a browser?

Comment: The path you used, `image.png`, is a relative path. You told WebClient to save the file in the current folder with the name `image.png`. Specify a different path if you want to save to a different folder.

Comment: `But I want to download that file in browser itself.` your code isn't using any web browser. `WebClient` is a class that makes HTTP requests. Why do you want a browser in the first place? You'd need Selenium or Playwright along with an installed version of Chrome or Chromium if you *really* need to use a browser for the job

Comment: Are you saying that you want to open the image in a browser that is launched by your C# code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open in default browser in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You haven't been very clear with your question. From what it sounds like, and where some of the other comments on here, you want to use a separate app running on a client's computer to download files from this URL. Is that correct? Or, do you operate a website and you want the user to be able to download the file using their browser, without any other app running directly on the client's computer?

Comment: In my current web app, there is link with Download text so once user click on that that file should download

Comment: It would really help if you could present a clearer and more complete description of what you're trying to do. Right now you're showing C# code but saying the user is downloading from a web browser. It's very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prompt a browser to download a response it would usually render, you can set the `Content-Disposition` header to “attachment” and provide a file name. This example assumes you’re executing a Razor Page handler and already have `path` from somewhere:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(path, out var mimeType);
    var basename = Path.GetFileName(path);

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={basename};");

    return new FileStreamResult(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path), mimeType);
}
```

Most browsers will show a download dialog or download the file to their default location using the filename from the header.

Instead of newing up the `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`, you should register it as a service and dependency-inject it into your page model’s constructor (or whatever you’re doing):

```
//program.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IContentTypeProvider, FileExtensionContentTypeProvider>();
```